# DLL settings from another DLL

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, dll

I have a MVC project that uses foo.dll, but that foo.dll uses smu.dll so basically I never reference smu.dll within my MVC project.  The problem I´m faced with is that within my MVC project I want to be able to store ssettings in web.config so that smu.dll will read.

We have tried to use both applicationsettings and appsettings without effect, when I refernce smu.dll directly from MVC or any other program it picks up the settings without a problem.  Do settings for smu.dll have to go into foo.dll app.config?

**EDIT**
Hello again friends, and thank you for your answers.

I found out what I was doing wrong after I read the comments.  In MVC there is a web.config within the Views-folder and one web.config in the root of the project.  When I used sectionGroup and applicationSettings in the "Views"-web.config the config was not read by the smu.dll.  I then changed the smu.dll to read appsettings instead, whereas I then put the appSettings into to "root"-web.config, then the config file was read by the dll.  I hope this makes sense but I am new to this and am still learning.

Anyway, this is finally working now :)

Comment: Can you show a complete example in code?  The concept of a "foo.dll app.config" doesn't really make sense because a class library isn't an application.  The configuration for the current application context should be available to any code running in that context, no matter how many levels of reference nesting exists between the executing assembly and the assembly in question.

Comment: #David you are absolutely right.  After reading your comment I went back to basics and changed my code in smu.dll along with my "root"-web.config in the MVC project, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have an MVC project, and two class libraries (foo & smu) ?

MVC -> Foo (via project reference)
Foo -> Smu (via project reference)

within AppSettings of web.config, you have a setting that smu should pick up?

Shouldn't Smu just accept a param, but not care where it comes from e.g.

if Smu was a data-access class, and it needed a connection string - all it needs to allow the user to do is send it a connection string? so, you could then send that from Foo (as this class can access your config settings) ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I edited my dll and MVC project after reading your post and it finally works, I edited my post  :)